# How do I continue configuration if apt-get was interrupted?

Tags: apt

In case there were some problems during the last `apt-get` operation, is there a command that checks if something has to be continued in `apt-get`?

Comment: If you get a `dpkg lock` error, see [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/99538/178596).

Comment: apt-get doesen't suggest anything here, but aptitude does, but a very strange suggestion on my laptop: http://askubuntu.com/questions/425516/aptituse-problem-using-mariadb-on-ubuntu-13-10-32bit

Comment: Depends where it was interrupted. Sometimes you interrupt dpkg sometimes you interrupt apt-get. apt-get itself can be interrupted any time since it's just an frontend for dpkg, dpkg otherwise is not for some operations.

Comment: If you're going down the rabbit hole through `sudo dpkg --configure some-package` and you encounter that SOME process is using SOME file `sudo lsof /path/to/file` can give you PIDs of the processes to `kill PID`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use the command:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

If that doesn't work, you can direct dpkg to finish setting up any packages that were only partially set up:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

If it doesn't work than you can reconfigure all the packages with:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a
```

Comment: I think reconfiguring all packages is not such a good idea and takes hours of manual work

Comment: is it the same with `sudo aptitude -f install`?

Comment: @rubo77: no, it is not the same but something similar.

Comment: On my problem the `-f` doesent make any difference, woth or without, I get no errors with apt-get but with atṕtitude, see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/425516/aptituse-problem-using-mariadb-on-ubuntu-13-10-32bit

Comment: Forget about aptitude, that works a little bit different.

Comment: Is it possible that you meant `dpkg --configure -a`? That's a subset of what `apt-get -f …` does if there are unconfigured packages. `dpkg-reconfigure` is an entirely different operation.

Comment: **Don't recommend** `apt -f install` - in certain scenarios it can purge your system from all software...

Answer (score 8):

In addition to the response by @Frantique, I would like to add:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

That solved my issue when the upgrade was interrupted during the process.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and in my case a Deb package was corrupted.
I had to

1. delete the cached packages from `/var/cache/apt/archives` with

   ```
   sudo apt-get clean
   ```
2. before running

   ```
   sudo apt-get -f install
   ```