# aptitude problem using mariadb repository on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: kernel, mysql, aptitude, mariadb

I installed mariadb 5.5 on my ubuntu laptop [like described here](https://askubuntu.com/a/300336/34298):

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/mariadb/repo/5.5/ubuntu $(lsb_release -c -s) main"
```

and it works fine so far, only there is something odd with aptitude: when I enter

```
sudo su
LANG=C 
aptitude install
```

I get these warnings:

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-3.11.0-12 linux-headers-3.11.0-12-generic mysql-client-core-5.5{b} mysql-server-core-5.5{b} 
0 packages upgraded, 4 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
Need to get 13.7 MB/21.4 MB of archives. After unpacking 100 MB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mariadb-server-core-5.5 : Conflicts: mysql-server-core-5.5 but 5.5.35-0ubuntu0.13.10.2 is to be installed.
 mysql-client-core-5.5 : Breaks: mysql-client-core-5.1 which is a virtual package.
 mysql-server-core-5.5 : Breaks: mysql-server-core-5.1 which is a virtual package.
 mariadb-client-core-5.5 : Conflicts: mysql-client-core-5.5 but 5.5.35-0ubuntu0.13.10.2 is to be installed.
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     mysql-client-core-5.5 [Not Installed]              
2)     mysql-server-core-5.5 [Not Installed]              

Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?]
```

I am confused and press **q** for quit!

This warning started after some days of usage of my PC using `aptitude` to keep it updated.

aptitude uses the mariadb repository now. this is my `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
#begin sources.list
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy main restricted
deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy main restricted

...

deb http://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/mariadb/repo/5.5/ubuntu saucy main
# deb-src http://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/mariadb/repo/5.5/ubuntu saucy main

#end sources.list
```

Why does it want to install an older kernel and do such things?

I am already on

```
uname -a
Linux myserver 3.11.0-17-generic #31-Ubuntu SMP Mon Feb 3 21:53:31 UTC 2014 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's ppas/sources conflicts... I had this multiple times, the thing is you have added a source (ppa) to your system where you withdraw/fetch updates that has packages of the same one as already one in the system and it's trusted (official). For example happened to me `linux-headers 3.x.x.9` installed but `linux-headers 3.x.x.8` is to be installed, because source you added has newer kernel recommended for your system than your official source. So that's why it happens and the solution is to remove or disable conflicting ppa in `/etc/apt/sources.list` and you'll get pass through it in no time :-)

How to find conflicting ppa you need to list its packages to see what packages it contains, I use `y-ppa-manager` by `webupd8` for this things, you can do it your own way.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/y-ppa-manager
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install y-ppa-manager
```

The other solution happened to be solved to avoid the conflict is to remove (untick) the main ubuntu repo in `/etc/apt/sources.list` for example `us.ubuntu.archive saucy main restricted` (or whatever distributive you have) then do `aptitude update` and `aptitude install` then move (tick) the main repo back in and disable the software repository in the sources.list repository.

Also others who be interested you may follow [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425981/how-can-you-add-a-second-main-repository-to-sources-list)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13243/discussion-between-rubo77-and-johnnyd)

Comment: we solved it in the chat: conclusion:
remove the main ubuntu repo `saucy main restricted`; then aptitude update and aptitude install; then move the main repo back in. thanks a lot!

Comment: anytime 24/7 :D

Comment: Do you want to add a second answer with the conclusion of our [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13243/discussion-between-rubo77-and-johnnyd)? With a description how to solve it (for others reading this post). Then I would mark that answer as the accepted one

Comment: yeah I did :-) it was a bit late yesterday and I was tired so I went to sleep :D