# Blank screen on startup after interrupted software update

Tags: 16.04

My Dell G3 laptop is on but it is stuck on this screen without any dektop icons or the keyboard buttons functionality. The desktop background G3 screen. The battery died while I was installing updates and when I turn it on it keeps doing that. Please would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have an update that failed halfway through. In order to recover that:

1. Choose "recovery mode" in the boot manager (grub). If you don't see the boot manager when restarting your computer, it might be hidden. (The boot manager is hidden, e.g. if you have only Ubuntu installed on your computer.) In that case press `Esc` right after the BIOS has loaded.
2. The recovery mode should take you to a root shell. There you can enter `sudo apt-get -f install` to repair any broken packages. Check out [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/425503/21008) for more info on that.
3. Reboot - now Ubuntu should load up successfully.

Comment: Thank youuu soo much for your help it worked I really appreciate it!!

Comment: My pleasure, @MalakKhaled! :)