Process of upgrading from Ubuntu 22 to 24 got interrupted and failed, when restarting desktop GUI doesn't load, wifi doesnt work, need help what to do
I was doing a regular Software Update, and after the usual update, a popup prompt asked me if I want to upgrade from Ubuntu 22 to 24. I accepted and started the process.
In the part where packages were being installed, there was a failure to download and install (or it wasn't available) pulseaudio. And I saw that the URL was trying to get it from the server of my country. The whole process just stopped after this without telling me what I was supposed to do. The OS desktop GUI was still running, but things were already altered and uninstalled.
EDIT: I then also noticed that I wasn't connected to the internet, and when I tried to open "Settings" in order to try to check the wifi settings, it wouldn't open.
EDIT: The answers in Major software missing after 24.04.1 LTS upgrade is something i cannot immediately follow because when I get to the Ubuntu console i don't have a wi-fi internet connection.
I was planning to go into the Software Updater GUI app and change the download source of the Ubuntu packages to the main Ubuntu server (instead of the one in my country) and then figure out how to resume or restart the upgrade process, but it could no longer be found in the GUI, even when I typed to search for it. I decided I was going to try to restart the computer and maybe it would appear again, but I accidentally clicked on "Lock" instead of "Restart", and once it got to the lock screen, I could not type in my password to unlock the computer because it seemed like the textbox kept on going out of focus and no characters could be typed in it. At this point, I force powered on and powered off my computer in order to restart. When the computer started again, the Ubuntu OS booted into a black CLI terminal instead of into a GUI. Right now, I have no idea what I'm supposed to do.
I have provided the details and story of how I ended up in the situation where the Ubuntu OS is not in a proper state, and hopefully, based on that, can someone recommend what action to take?

You can try finish installation from a live usb with a chroot environment, similar to https://askubuntu.com/questions/145241/how-do-i-run-update-grub-from-a-livecd, and continue installation: https://askubuntu.com/a/425503/631600
No guarantee that it works, as the updater might do other things as well.

Just to make sure it's clear, in my situation, I can boot into Ubuntu (not Grub), but the Ubuntu interface is a terminal and not a desktop GUI. I actually tried sudo dpkg --configure -a in that terminal and nothing happened after pressing enter.
If going to try booting from live usb, is that usb supposed to be 22 or 24 to try to continue the upgrade?

If you wish to end up with a 24.04 system, you should install that, then reload your data from your backups. Trying to fix a half upgraded system would be a lot more trouble than that.

This question is similar to: Major software missing after 24.04.1 LTS upgrade. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I believe this is different because of the fact that the upgrade got interrupted and failed to reach the end due to the failure to download and install pulseaudio. This is not something that happened in "Major software missing after 24.04.1 LTS upgrade". I mention in the question that the upgrade process got interrupted and failed. The other topic sounds like it reached what was declared as finished and asked the user to reboot, then he hit the console screen after boot.

just edited now. In the other thread situation, he also doesn't say he has no internet connection, another difference in my case im not connected to the internet when i boot.

Then, you should try boot from live usb (I guess it doesn't matter if the usb is 22.04 or 24.04), then create the chroot environment, then do the steps from https://askubuntu.com/questions/1524989/major-software-missing-after-24-04-1-lts-upgrade. If these steps won't help, make a data backup (you can do that also from a live usb) and do a reinstall.

I'm willing to accept pLumo's answer:

Then, you should try boot from live usb (I guess it doesn't matter if
the usb is 22.04 or 24.04), then create the chroot environment, then
do the steps from askubuntu.com/questions/1524989/…. If these steps
won't help, make a data backup (you can do that also from a live usb)
and do a reinstall.

–
pLumo
Thanks
